# MS Graph Events PATCH

Tags: c#, .net, microsoft-graph-api

I cannot update an Event over MS Graph

```
var meeting = events.CurrentPage.First(m => m.Subject.Contains("Test title"));
meeting.Subject = "test!";
await graphClient.Users[roomEmail].Events[meeting.Id].Request().PutResponseAsync(meeting);
```

I'm receiving

[image]

I have permissions
Microsoft Graph: Calendars.ReadWrite, User.Read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead

```
var meeting = events.CurrentPage.First(m => m.Subject.Contains("Test title"));
meeting.Subject = "test!";
await graphClient.Users[roomEmail].Events[meeting.Id].Request().UpdateAsync(meeting);
```

Comment: it passed and now I don't see the change in Outlook but from the API it comes changed 
can I force somehow Outlook to display the changes? 
I checked on Outlook and Outlook365

Comment: It should show it in outlook, but keep in mind you are updating the roomEmail calendar, so if you want to see the changes you need to login to the roomEmail outlook. If you want all attendees calendars to be updated, you would need to update it through the organizers email account.

Comment: hmm... so in order to create a background task that changes everything (let's say the title for all attendees) I would need to iterate over each attendee + have access to their calendars and make N calls to the API?

Comment: That would work as well, but that is not what I meant. When user-x@something.com create a calendar event and invites 10 attendees, then user-x is the organizer of the event. So if you make changes to the event through  user-x agenda then every attendees calendar gets an update.

Comment: @kolek could you please accept the answer, if it solved the question you asked? :))

Comment: I tried to verify the answer but I'm stuck fighting for proper access, but I'm quite sure that it's the correct answer. Thank you very much for the help :)